# RX: How to concat a Snapshot stream and an Update stream?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, system.reactive

I've been trying to create an observable which streams a state-of-the-world (snapshot) from a repository cache, followed by live updates from a separate feed. The catch is that the snapshot call is blocking, so the updates have to be buffered during that time.

This is what I've come up with, a little simplified. The **GetStream()** method is the one I'm concerned with. I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant solution. Assume GetDataFeed() pulses updates to the cache all day long.

```
private static readonly IConnectableObservable<long> _updateStream;

public static Constructor()
{
      _updateStream = GetDataFeed().Publish();
      _updateStream.Connect();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      _updateStream.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
      Console.ReadLine();
      GetStream().Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine("Stream: " + l));
      Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IObservable<long> GetStream()
{
      return Observable.Create<long>(observer =>
            {
                  var bufferedStream = new ReplaySubject<long>();
                  _updateStream.Subscribe(bufferedStream);
                  var data = GetSnapshot();
                  // This returns the ticks from GetSnapshot
                  //  followed by the buffered ticks from _updateStream
                  //  followed by any subsequent ticks from _updateStream
                  data.ToObservable().Concat(bufferedStream).Subscribe(observer);

                  return Disposable.Empty;
            });
}

private static IObservable<long> GetDataFeed()
{
      var feed = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      return Observable.Create<long>(observer =>
      {
            feed.Subscribe(observer);
            return Disposable.Empty;
      });
}
```

Popular opinion opposes Subjects as they are not 'functional', but I can't find a way of doing this without a ReplaySubject. The Replay filter on a hot observable wouldn't work because it would replay everything (potentially a whole day's worth of stale updates).

I'm also concerned about race conditions. Is there a way to guarantee sequencing of some sort, should an earlier update be buffered before the snapshot? Can the whole thing be done more safely and elegantly with other RX operators?

Thanks.

-Will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you use a `ReplaySubject` or the `Replay` function really makes no difference.  `Replay` uses a `ReplaySubject` under the hood.  I'll also note that you are leaking subscriptions like mad, which can cause a resource leak.  Also, you put no limit on the size of the replay buffer.  If you watch the observable all day long, then that replay buffer will keep growing and growing.  You should put a limit on it to prevent that.

Here is an updated version of `GetStream`.  In this version I take the simplistic approach of just limitting the `Replay` to the most recent 1 minute of data.  This assumes that `GetData` will always complete *and* the observer will observe the results within that 1 minute.  Your mileage may vary and you can probably improve upon this scheme.  But at least this way when you have watched the observable all day long, that buffer will not have grown unbounded and will still only contain a minute's worth of updates.

```
public static IObservable<long> GetStream()
{
    return Observable.Create<long>(observer =>
    {
        var updateStreamSubscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var sequenceDisposable = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(updateStreamDisposable, sequenceDisposable);

        // start buffering the updates
        var bufferedStream = _updateStream.Replay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        updateStreamSubscription.Disposable = bufferedStream.Connect();

        // now retrieve the initial snapshot data
        var data = GetSnapshot();

        // subscribe to the snapshot followed by the buffered data
        sequenceDisposable.Disposable = data.ToObservable().Concat(bufferedStream).subscribe(observer);

        // return the composite disposable which will unsubscribe when the observer wishes
        return subscriptions;
    });
}
```

As for your questions about race conditions and filtering out "old" updates...if your snapshot data includes some sort of version information, and your update stream also providers version information, then you can effectively measure the latest version returned by your snapshot query and then filter the buffered stream to ignore values for older versions.  Here is a rough example:

```
public static IObservable<long> GetStream()
{
    return Observable.Create<long>(observer =>
    {
        var updateStreamSubscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var sequenceDisposable = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(updateStreamDisposable, sequenceDisposable);

        // start buffering the updates
        var bufferedStream = _updateStream.Replay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        updateStreamSubscription.Disposable = bufferedStream.Connect();

        // now retrieve the initial snapshot data
        var data = GetSnapshot();

        var snapshotVersion = data.Length > 0 ? data[data.Length - 1].Version : 0;
        var filteredUpdates = bufferedStream.Where(update => update.Version > snapshotVersion);

        // subscribe to the snapshot followed by the buffered data
        sequenceDisposable.Disposable = data.ToObservable().Concat(filteredUpdates).subscribe(observer);

        // return the composite disposable which will unsubscribe when the observer wishes
        return subscriptions;
    });
}
```

I have successfully used this pattern when merging live updates with a stored snapshot.  I haven't yet found an elegant Rx operator that already does this without any race conditions.  But the above method could probably be turned into such. :)

Edit: Note I have left out error handling in the examples above.  In theory the call to `GetSnapshot` could fail and you'd leak the subscription to the update stream.  I suggest wrapping everything after the `CompositeDisposable` declaration in a `try/catch` block, and in the catch handler, ensure call `subscriptions.Dispose()` before re-throwing the exception.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize you could call Replay at the moment of subscription! When you say that I'm leaking subscriptions, is that solved by wrapping the streams into the  CompositeDisposable? Thanks!

Comment: By leaking subscriptions, I mean that you were calling `Subscribe` but ignoring the returned `IDisposable` and thus providing no way to ever unsubscribe from that stream.  Generally speaking, when you use `Observable.Create` to create an observable, you want to ensure that any calls to subscribe you make are unsubscribed properly when the disposable you return is disposed.  In this case, we have 2 calls to subscribe (well, 1 subscribe and 1 connect), so we want to make sure that both disposables are disposed.  CompositeDisposables are good for that purpose.